# Postgresql does not update last updated row by trigger

Tags: postgresql

I created a trigger. When I update a row the trigger before doesn't work. Later, when I update a row second time the trigger is working. Why doesn't work before?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_em_z_module_mod_codes
  before UPDATE
ON emlakmuayene.em_z_module
FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE emlakmuayene.update_em_z_module_mod_codes();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emlakmuayene.update_em_z_module_mod_codes()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN   
        if (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then 
        if new.mod_codes_ids is not null  then      
        new.mod_codes=
        (
        SELECT translate(array_Agg(pages)::Text,'{}','') as mod_codes 
        FROM emlakmuayene.em_z_module  t1 
        join emlakmuayene.em_z_order_pages_view  t2 
        on t2.id_seq_x = any ( ('{'||t1.mod_codes_ids||'}')::bigint[]) where t1.id_Seq_X=new.id_seq_x  group by t1.id_Seq_X );          
        end if ;
        end if;
    RETURN new;
    END;    
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: please show some code - how it works and how it does not

Answer (score 0):

After added my trigger `IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN RETURN NEW;` 
and change my 
            update sql `update  emlakmuayene.em_z_module t1 
            set  mod_codes = t2.mod_codes  ,reg=1
            from    (
            SELECT t1.id_Seq_x ,translate(array_Agg(pages)::Text,'{}','') as mod_codes 
            FROM emlakmuayene.em_z_module  t1 
            join emlakmuayene.em_z_order_pages_view  t2 
            on t2.id_seq_x = any ( ('{'||t1.mod_codes_ids||'}')::bigint[]) 
            where t1.id_seq_x=new.id_seq_x
            group by t1.id_Seq_X 
                ) t2
            where  t1.id_seq_x=T2.id_seq_x;` is working

then my trigger 
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emlakmuayene.update_em_z_module_mod_codes()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
        BEGIN

            IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
                RETURN NEW;
                END IF;
            update  emlakmuayene.em_z_module t1 set  mod_codes = t2.mod_codes  ,reg=1
            from    (
            SELECT t1.id_Seq_x ,translate(array_Agg(pages)::Text,'{}','') as mod_codes 
            FROM emlakmuayene.em_z_module  t1 
            join emlakmuayene.em_z_order_pages_view  t2 
            on t2.id_seq_x = any ( ('{'||t1.mod_codes_ids||'}')::bigint[]) 
            where t1.id_seq_x=new.id_seq_x
            group by t1.id_Seq_X 
                ) t2
            where  t1.id_seq_x=T2.id_seq_x;
            return new;
        END;

    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION emlakmuayene.update_em_z_module_mod_codes()
  OWNER TO tuvimer_ortak`